# Error TPL PHP Prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am working on Prestashop and I would like to retrieve the data from a table I created in my database. I've been on it for 2 days and nothing works, I'll go crazy.

Here is the code I put in my ProductController.php file:

```
    private function GetAvailableAttributes($id_produit, $id_compte, $note)
    {      
    global $smarty;  
$sql = 'SELECT id_produit, id_compte, note
        FROM `'.'ps_product_avis';
    $ess=mysql_result($sql,0);
$smarty->assign('contact', $ess);
    }
```

Here is the code put in the product.tpl file:

```
<li>test :{$contact}</li>
```

Here's the mistake it gives:

[image: Error message]

Could one of you save me and explain where the problem comes from please?

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is called that method?

Comment: It is called for each product page.

Comment: No, I mean where in which method of the controller you call this method?

Comment: I don't understand. I want display the data of my database in all my product page. 
I want to create a product rating area.

Comment: Ok, let's start from the begin... You have add your custom method `GetAvailableAttributes` in the controller (the `ProductController.php`), now that method in which part of the `ProductController` is called?

Comment: I add it to the end of my ProductController : 
https://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=55816820170710174837untitledSublimeTextUNREGISTERED.png

Comment: My friend, I can't be more clear of this, we have difficulty understanding us :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PrestaShop 1.7 (and also 1.5 and 1.6) the global var `$smarty` was deprecated.
You have made various errors, I'll try to explain with the corrections :)

Change your code in this:

```
private function GetAvailableAttributes($id_produit, $id_compte, $note)
{
    /* global $smarty; DEPRECATED */ 
    $sql = 'SELECT id_produit, id_compte, note
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_avis`';
    /* Use always _DB_PREFIX_ constant var */

    /* $ess=mysql_result($sql,0); Use Db class instead of this old method */
    $ess = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);

    /* $smarty->assign('contact', $ess); Deprecated use */
    $this->context->smarty->assign('contact', $ess);
}
```

Remember that the `executeS` method returns a set of array, also if there is one element to return.

So your array will be like this:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        'id_produit' => 1,
        'id_compte' => 1,
        'note' => 'my note'
    )
);
```

In smarty to print single element you should do something like this:

```
{$contact[0]['note']}
```

It will print `my note`.

That's all :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I understand all your indications but i have the same error :(

Comment: Perfect for the php but when i add {$contact[0]['note']} in the TPL i have an error.

Comment: make a {$contact|var_dump} and see what display. However your query should be modified, you should add the id_product, because that query grab all the products that you have in the database.

Comment: With this : <li>test :{$contact|var_dump}</li>
I have the same error :

in smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code line 532
at ErrorHandler->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: contact', 'www/vendor/prestashop/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code', '532', array('_smarty_tpl' => object(Smarty_Dev_Template), '_tpl_stack' => array(), '_from' => array())) in smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code line 532

Comment: {$contact|var_dump} returns as result  "NULL }".

Comment: All is well. I put the code of the function in public function initContent () and now everything works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Alleluja! :D You're welcome ;) If you have any other question I'm here ;)